# return certain values from a multi-array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to be able to return only the values of a certain key from an array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
           (
              [LEVEL] => => Array
                         (
                            [SCORE] => 10
                         )
           )
    [1] => Array
           (
              [LEVEL] => Array
                         (
                            [SCORE] => 40
                         )
           )
)
```

I'm trying to make the array grab all scores:

```
Array(10,40)
```

I can do it easily with a foreach loop, but I'm trying to use an existing php function.

Comment: What's the problem with not using a foreach loop if it is so easy? Name the function `grabScores(10,40)` and be done with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
function get_score($a) {
    return $a['LEVEL']['SCORE'];
};

$arr = array(
    array(
        'LEVEL' => array(
            'SCORE' => 10
        )
    ),
    array(
        'LEVEL' => array(
            'SCORE' => 40
        )
    )
);

print_r(array_map('get_score', $arr));
```